# Pushing temporary into vector in c++

Tags: c++

How many copies happen/object exist in the following, assuming that normal compiler optimizations are enabled:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
v.push_back(MyClass());
```

If it is not exactly 1 object creation and 0 copying, What can I do (including changes in `MyClass`) to achieve that, since it seems to me that that is all that should really be necessary?

Comment: are you sure `v.push_back(v());`?

Comment: "assuming that normal compiler optimizations are enabled"? No such things as "normal compiler optimizations" - depends on the compiler, on the used compiler options, etc.

Comment: I suppose it's more something like v.push_back(MyClass());

Comment: @KirilKirov I mean without specifying particular compiler flags. Say, `release` in VS, or `-O2` or `-O3` in gcc. This seems trivial enough that all compilers should take care of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the constructor of `MyClass` has side-effects, then in C++03 the copy is not permitted to be elided. That's because the temporary object that's the source of the copy has been bound to a reference (the parameter of `push_back`).

If the copy constructor of `MyClass` has no side-effects then the compiler is permitted to optimize it away under the "as-if" rule. I think the only sensible way to determine whether it actually has done so with "normal optimizations" is to inspect the emitted code. Different people have different ideas what's normal, and a given compiler might be sensitive to the details of `MyClass`. My guess is that what this amounts to is whether or not the compiler (or linker) inlines everything in sight. If it does then it will probably optimize, if it doesn't then it won't. So even the size of the constructor code might be relevant, never mind what it does.

So I think the main thing you can do is to ensure that both the default and the copy constructor of `MyClass` have no side-effects and are available to be inlined. If they're not available then of course the compiler will assume that they could have side-effects and will do the copy. If link-time optimization is a normal compiler option for you, then you don't have to do much to make them available. Otherwise, if they're user-defined then do it in the header file that defines `MyClass`. You might be able to get away with the default constructor having certain kinds of side-effects: if the effects don't depend on the address of the temporary being different from the address of the vector element then "as-if" still applies.

In C++11 you have a move (that likewise must not be elided if it has side-effects), but you can use `v.emplace_back()` to avoid that. The move would call the move constructor of `MyClass` if it has one, otherwise the copy constructor, and everything I say above about "as-if" applies to moves. `emplace_back()` calls the no-args constructor to construct the vector element (or if you pass arguments to `emplace_back` then whatever constructor matches those args), which I think is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
v.push_back(MyClass());
```

None.  The temporary will cause the move version of push_back to be called.  Even the move construction will most likely be elided.

Comment: And if the compiler is not a C++11 compiler?

Comment: None what? I assume you mean no copies and only one creation?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Than it's out-of-date.

Comment: Is this true only for c++11? Is it dependent on move constructors (or whatever they are called)?

Comment: There are still many companies that are using pre-C++11 compilers, or where the C++11 support is not fully (or even barely) implemented.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: and there is still code being maintained in cobol and fortran - an unqualified reference to "C++" means by default the current ratified standard as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: examples of companies using pre-C++11 compilers include *all companies that use C++*, since at time of writing there are no complete C++11 compilers ;-) I agree that it's wrong to dismiss such compilers as "out-of-date", but I also think it's reasonable to offer C++11 answers to C++ questions, especially when they use only C++11 features that are quite widely implemented.

Comment: The current release versions of gcc, clang and msvc all have 90%+ support of the current standard - and they have certainly had move semantics for several years now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C++11 compiler, you can use [emplace_back](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/dd647620.aspx) to construct the element at the end of the vector, zero copies necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In C++03, you would have a construction and a copy, plus destruction of the temporary.

If your compiler supports C++11 and MyClass defines a move constructor, then you have one construction and a move.

As mentionned by Timbo, you can also use emplace_back to avoid the move, the object being constructed in-place.